# Allow access to subfolder using web.config

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, web-config

I have a windows shared host, and I uploaded 2 codeigniter programmes to it 
The first app is in the `httpdocs` folder and the other one is in the `admin` subfolder inside the `httpdocs` folder

Here's what it looks like

```
httpdocs
|-----admin
      |----application
      |----system
      |----......
|-----application
|-----system
|----......
```

The outer program has its `web.config` file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="codeigniter" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{R:1}" pattern="!^(index\.php|favicon\.ico|assets|js|css|fa|fonts|bootstrap|build|dist|js|plugins)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that `web.config` is preventing me from accessing the program inside  `admin` folder,
is there anyway I can exclude that folder from that rule ?